# How would you write a "Dmaj -> Gmaj -> Fmaj" chord progression using Roman numerals?

Tags: chord-progressions, roman-numerals

Seems like a simple question... song seems to be in key of D. But I cannot figure out how to describe the progression using the chord progression Roman numerals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the key of D, this would be `I -> IV -> bIII`.

However, much depends on the context. For example, if the next chord were B♭maj, the the Fmaj would most likely be written as `V/bVI`.

Comment: Or it could be `C: V/V V IV`

Comment: Thank you, the song I have in mind is "Wilco - Handshake Drugs" Sorry I thought those were the only three chords, but Cmaj also makes an appearance during the chorus. Would it still be considered key of D?

Comment: @mattacular Possibly. Cmaj could be bVII chord, borrowed from D minor. However, it all depends on context. As Todd Wilcox points out, the chord progression as is could be interpreted in C major, so the C chord in the chorus would be consistent with that.